# disable italic font in gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, fonts, gnome-terminal

I use `gnome-terminal` on Debian 8 with `Source Code Pro Regular` as the font (the font comes with the TeXLive distribution).

How can I disable the use of italics universally in the terminal?

One reason for this: when searching a `man` page, the search results are highlighted with italics, which is difficult for me to spot.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-terminal` does not have such an option. You might tweak its source (actually `vte`'s), or configure `fontconfig` so that the italic version of your chosen font happens to be non-italic, or configure your `man` viewer (e.g. `less`) not to use italics.